# JS/Lodash/Nodejs: Printing name of variable being iterated upon within lodash foreach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have the following loop structure that iterates over an array of object refs, does something for each defined object and should print out the name of the undefined object.

For that I need to print the actual object name that was passed into the iterator.

Is there any operator that provides name of the parameter passed into the iteratee function?

```
 //couple of objects with some data
    var a = { .... };
    var b = { .... };
    //undefined object
    var c;
    var d;    
    var e;
   .
   .
   .
   .
   var someNthVar;

_.forEach (
    [a,b,c,d,e,....],
    function (obj) {
         if (obj) {
             //do something
         } else {             
             //PROBLEM!!! How do i specify that variable 'c' is the one that is undefined
             //log undefined variables
             console.log('Undefined variable: ' + obj.variableName);
         }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any operator that provides name of the parameter passed into the iteratee function?

No. You can define a list of names and associate them by index, though:

```
const names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

[a, b, c].forEach((obj, i) => {
    if (!obj) {
        throw new Error(`${names[i]} missing a value`);
    }

    // do something
});
```

Comment: Ok -thanks- but what if this list is dynamic - what if there is a dynamic array of objects read from a file - how would it work in that case

Comment: @BabyGroot: What would you name those objects?

Comment: sorry for a loose question body earlier and thanks for the effort - I have made the question bit more explicit. Thanks!

Comment: In short - is it possible to do this without having to make an array of names in addition?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a javascript object to hold your values?

That way you could write something like the following, using the similar [forIn](https://lodash.com/docs#forIn);

```
var objects = {
    a: {...},
    b: {...},
    c: undefined,
    d: {...}
}

_.forIn(objects, function(value, name){
    if (!value) {
        throw new Error(`${name} is missing a value`);
    }
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: yes - not my case though, objects are dynamic and pre-loaded.

Comment: May I ask how either of those prevent you from being able to do it this way? In fact, wouldn't doing it this way make it easier?

Comment: The object definitions are not defined statically so I can't write:

var objects = {
    a: {...},
    b: {...},
    c: undefined,
    d: {...}
}

Comment: How are they defined? I'm not sure how rendering `var a = {..}` is any easier than rendering `a: {...}`. Perhaps if you elaborated on your use-case I could understand where you're coming from...

Comment: Usually I will get the object populated from another user who would juts be sending over the object. This is an elaborate framework here where a, b ,c d are objects with fixed names but dynamic data updated on run-time and sourced via json text files.